# How may I define the "Group table view" pattern as background programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How may I define the "Group table view" pattern as background programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group table view pattern is a property of `UIColor`:

```
[someView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the UIColor class method [`groupTableViewBackgroundColor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/groupTableViewBackgroundColor)

EG:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
```

(or if you don't like dot notation:`[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];`)